# Bar-chart toggling between 3 variables in an array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart that is using the following data set to represent three dimensions:

```
var dataset = [
  [5, 23, 75],
  [10, 14, 34],
  [13, 67, 23],
  [19, 10, 65],
  [21, 42, 29],
  [25, 25, 25],
  [22, 90, 30],
  [18, 57, 17],
  [15, 25, 35],
  [13, 26, 39],
  [11, 17, 85],
  [12, 36, 24],
  [15, 60, 45],
  [20, 41, 11],
  [18, 77, 33],
  [17, 85, 55],
  [16, 23, 44],
  [18, 35, 23],
  [23, 55, 15],
  [25, 45, 100]
];
```

have a bar chart constructed from svg  elements and a function that re-sorts the bar chart:

```
var sortBars = function() {

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      if (sortOrder) {
        return d3.ascending(a[0], b[0]);
      }
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i);
    });
  svg.selectAll("text")
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      if (sortOrder) {
        return d3.ascending(a[0], b[0]);
      }
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i) + 2.5;
    });
};
```

This re-sorts the bars/text by the first variable in the array, but I want the user to see the other two variables (a[1],b[1] & a[2],b[2]) successively when they click the bars. I am doing this for a project and my instructor suggested using the modulus (%) operator to toggle between these variables, but I am coming up with nothing! I have tried making an if...else function to toggle between two variables, but I don't think that this is the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your instructor tried to say is that if you set up a counter, `counter % 3` will return the remainder of the division by 3, effectively looping through 0, 1 and 2. Have a look here:

```js
console.log(d3.range(50).map(d => d % 3).join())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

So, in your case, we can set up a counter and using the remainder operator for sorting the bars. To avoid creating a global counter, I'll create a closure here instead:

```
bars.on("click", sortBars());

function sortBars() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function() {
    ++counter;
    bars.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(a[counter % 3], b[counter % 3]);
      })
      .transition()
      .attr("x", (_, i) => i * 15)
  }
};
```

Here is a demo using your data:

```js
var dataset = [
  [5, 23, 75],
  [10, 14, 34],
  [13, 67, 23],
  [19, 10, 65],
  [21, 42, 29],
  [25, 25, 25],
  [22, 90, 30],
  [18, 57, 17],
  [15, 25, 35],
  [13, 26, 39],
  [11, 17, 85],
  [12, 36, 24],
  [15, 60, 45],
  [20, 41, 11],
  [18, 77, 33],
  [17, 85, 55],
  [16, 23, 44],
  [18, 35, 23],
  [23, 55, 15],
  [25, 45, 100]
];

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const bars = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (_, i) => i * 15)
  .attr("width", 12)
  .attr("y", d => 150 - d[0] * 4)
  .attr("height", d => d[0] * 4);

bars.on("click", sortBars());

function sortBars() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function() {
    ++counter;
    bars.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(a[counter % 3], b[counter % 3]);
      })
      .transition()
      .attr("x", (_, i) => i * 15)
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! For a further question: how would I return the bar chart back to how it was organized after the 3rd variable?

Comment: Just sort the bars by their data indices.